# response.toString() return empty array with volley

Tags: php, android, android-volley

i am getting empty array on response.toString() when get json response with volley. its very annoying because it fine earlier.
this is my android code

```
// untuk menampilkan semua data pada listview
private void getOutbox(final CallBack callBack) {

    // membuat request JSON
    JsonArrayRequest jArr = new JsonArrayRequest(url_outbox, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                try {
                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        int idx = obj.getInt(TAG_ID);
                        String pesanx = obj.getString(TAG_PESAN);
                        String nohpx = obj.getString(TAG_SENTTO);

                        id.add(idx);
                        noHp.add(nohpx);
                        pesan.add(pesanx);
                    }
                    callBack.onSuccess(id, noHp, pesan);


                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    });
    // menambah request ke request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jArr);
}
```

and then this my php file

```
<?php 
include "koneksi.php";

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, sentTo, Message FROM sms_outbox where status IS NULL");

$json = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    $json[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($json);

mysql_close($connect);
```

?>

please anyone help me because of this, i cant get value from my database. any suggest would be appreciated

logcat:

```
03-31 22:24:59.160 2855-3252/id.prasetyo.mysms I/qtaguid: Failed write_ctrl(u 45) res=-1 errno=22
```

03-31 22:24:59.160 2855-3252/id.prasetyo.mysms I/qtaguid: Untagging socket 45 failed errno=-22
03-31 22:24:59.160 2855-3252/id.prasetyo.mysms W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: untagSocket(45) failed with errno -22
03-31 22:24:59.168 2855-2855/id.prasetyo.mysms D/MainActivity: []

Comment: Well echo some more. Just add debug info in your echo()'s.

Comment: sorry, i am beginner in android, can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: Just add several times something to your $json array.

Comment: add several times something ? what do you mean ?

Comment: Well you should echo something. Which you then can read in your app. You will receive nothing now if there are no rows for instance.